# How to disable Volume / Headphone safety volume notifications for an external speaker?

Tags: bluetooth, notifications, headphones, speakers

Getting headphone safety notifications for an external speaker, thing is I have to turn the bluetooth volume to full (or >80%) for this device to work properly as it has it's own amplifier and volume control.

It's a big jambox but ideally the solution isn't device specific. iOS 16.

How can I stop this device from causing safety notifications?

Answer (score 0):

We can stop this by marking the device as a speaker.

1. Settings
2. Bluetooth
3. Find device under `My Devices` and touch the `(i)` circle.
4. Device Type
5. mark it as `Speaker`

Now it will stop identifying it as headphones.